# Shortcut key to activate project explorer in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to find out the shortcut key to activate the project explorer in eclipse. I usually use cmd+F12 key to activate the editor, however i have to rely on mouse to move to a project explorer.

Is there a shortcut key available for that ? If not can it be configured ?

Comment: CTRL+F7, this will iterate through open windows.. once you reach the project explorer, hit enter, voila you will be there.

Comment: Thanks Anantha, Cmd/Ctrl + F7 works.

Answer (score 24):

Go to **Window --> Preferences --> Click on General --> Keys**. You will see

[image]

Now, below **Scheme** there is textbox, type `project explorer`. You will see

[image]

Select **Show View** from the grid. In **Binding** type the short key which ever you want. I typed **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Q**. Then click on Apply and OK.

If you want to assign a short key and that short key exists then you will see in **Conflicts:** table.

Some useful shortcuts are

1. [103 shortcuts](https://shortcutworld.com/Eclipse/win/Eclipse-Helios_Shortcuts)
2. [more shortcuts](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key)

Comment: This will be shortcut to **show** Project Explorer, not for **activate** it.
**Anantha Sharma**'s comment at the original post is pretty good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

By activate do you mean to open the project?
This shortcut is not set by default. Go to Preferences->keys and serach for open project and set shortcut of your choice.

But to apply this shortcut you will have to reach that project. So set a shortcut to reach Project explorer [same way as explained above] , use arrow keys to reach project and then use your open project shortcut. Easiest way use mouse :)

Answer (score 2):

Customise the `Show View` dialog.

The Eclipse defaults don't include the Project Explorer view, so you must add that.

From [eclipseonetips.com](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/15/the-fastest-ways-to-navigate-views-in-eclipse-using-the-keyboard/):

> The Show View commands are activated by pressing `Alt`+`Shift`+`Q`, then the letter for the relevant view, eg. to navigate to the Package Explorer, press `Alt`+`Shift`+`Q`, `P`.

So pressing `Alt`+`Shift`+`Q` will cause the `Show View` dialog to pop up where you can select the view you want with the cursor arrows, the mouse or the `P`.

Follow the instructions given in Aniket Kulkami's answer and add `Alt`+`Shift`+`Q`,`R` to the Project Explorer Show View item. Then you will see the option appear in the `Show View` dialog along with the other views it's possible to navigate to, and `R` will select it.

It might also make sense for you to remove the `P` from the Package Explorer view so you can use it for the Project Explorer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+Shift+L` to open the Key Assist. All key shortcuts are available in key assist, see what you need is available there or not

Comment: This shortcut is not available there.